# WooCommerce shop page orderby

Tags: plugins, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Recently I found that, WooCommerce was removed the `Display` option from WooCommerce admin settings. So that, my shop page all products currently showing in ascending order. But, I want to show them in descending order. This means that I want to keep the new products above always. Now I am using the WooCommerce with version of 3.3.5 and the theme name is storefront.

TIA

Comment: The display settings are in the Customiser now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce have moved this setting to the WordPress Customizer. From your WordPress admin area, browse to: `Appearance -> Customise`

Then, from within the customiser, you can find the setting here: `WooCommerce -> Product Catalogue` and simply change the order under the option 'Default Product Sorting'